# Stripe Payment Intent: update and confirm for change in payment amount

Tags: stripe-payments, e-commerce

I am implementing stripe for an online shopping site that runs on a "balance" system, where the user enters how much money they would like to deposit into their trading balance and submits credit card info to make the deposit.

I can't figure out how to avoid making two sequential api calls to stripe at the time of payment confirmation: one to update the pay amount with the current value of the deposit from an html form, and one to [confirm payment intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm).

**Here are the constraints as I understand them:**

1. Stripe requires the [creation of a Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create) in order to populate an iframe with their credit card form.
2. In order to have a streamlined deposit experience, I want the `<input>` on my site where the user enters the deposit amount to be active and present at the same time as and in the same modal as the the stripe iframe
3. The stripe [Confirm Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm) api appears to not allow you to send a new payment "amount" at the time of confirmation.  When I send a new amount parameter from the client like so: `stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {payment_method:{card:stripeCardElement}, amount:depositAmount})`, I receive an error:
   `{code: "parameter_unknown",  doc_url: "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown", message: "Received unknown parameter: amount", param: "amount", payment_intent: Object { id: "pi_1IV21CGYTBSx8jHSRsJ1bLls", object: "payment_intent", amount: 2000, … }, type: "invalid_request_error"}`.  Note that the "amount" parameter works fine for an update payment api call (see #4 below)
4. The [Payment Intent Update](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update) api requires you to subsequently confirm the payment intent after the update completes and sends a response back to the client.  From the stripe documentation: "Depending on which properties you update, you may need to confirm the PaymentIntent again. For example, updating the payment_method will always require you to confirm the PaymentIntent again. If you prefer to update and confirm at the same time, we recommend updating properties via the confirm API instead."

If this is so, it requires my payment confirmation workflow to involve two synchronous trips to the stripe api: the first to update the amount, the second to confirm payment.  Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

`amount` isn't an acceptable parameter of `confirmCardPayment`. You have to specify the `amount` when you create the `PaymentIntent` server-sided. As you stated, it's also not available for update via `confirm` of the `PaymentIntent`. However, depending on your flow, you can update the `amount` via updating the `PaymentIntent`, before you `confirm` it: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update#update_payment_intent-amount. You can do this synchronously or asynchronously via webhook.